# How to remove focus from QListWidget item

Tags: python, focus, selection, pyside, qlistwidget

I am using PySide and I have a QListWidget. I made a dummy item and placed it at the top of the QListWidget. I did this so when the tool first opens, no useful item is selected by default.  I do not like that this empty item is "highlighted", revealing the item to the user.  How can I get rid of this outline/highlight? I will include an image of the issue:

[image]

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: What do you mean by *making it appear active, or selected*?

Comment: So you see the dotted, outline around the empty spot at the top of the new-texture box? Where the red arrows are pointing. I would like that outline to go away.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this behavior but in my case it does not generate it. That's why I'm asking you for an [MCVE]

Comment: For ref. Here is part of my code. It was written to run inside of a Maya session with textures in the hypershade.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can achieve this with an item-delegate:

```
class NoFocusDelegate(QStyledItemDelegate):
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        option.state = QStyle.State_None
        super(NoFocusDelegate, self).paint(painter, option, index)

self.listWidget.setItemDelegateForRow(0, NoFocusDelegate(self))
```

However, a better solution would be to get rid of the dummy item and just clear the focus by setting an invalid current index:

```
self.listWidget.setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex())
```

Now no item will be highlighted, and `currentItem()` will return `None` and `currentRow()` will return `-1` until the user explicitly selects an item.

Comment: Thanks again, Ekhumoro. The QmodelIndex line worked perfectly. I can not say I fully understand why it worked yet, but it solved the issue and I got rid of the dummy items! I approved this answer.